# How to unset link to <span> tagging in Advanced PDF/HTML Templates in NetSuite?

Tags: html, netsuite, freemarker, pdfhtml

We're having some problems in our PDF Templates. We have a part/code of PDF Template, code below:

```
<td style="font-size:8.0pt"><br />Regards,<br /><br />
                <span style="font-size:8.0pt"><b>${record.salesrep}</b></span><br />
                <span style="font-size:8.0pt"><b>${record.salesrep.custentity_job_title}</b></span><br />
                <span style="font-size:8.0pt">Mobile: ${record.salesrep.mobilephone}</span><br />
                <span style="font-size:8.0pt">Email: ${record.salesrep.email}</span><br />
                <span style="font-size:8.0pt">Website: </span><span
                  style="color:blue">www.accesshire.ae</span><br />
                <span style="font-size:8.0pt">Landline: </span><span style="color:blue">800 888 4473</span>
              </td>
```

On this code, **Email: ${record.salesrep.email}** and **[www.accesshire.ae](http://www.accesshire.ae)** are encapsulated in `<span>` tagging. However, when loaded/printed, once you hover over the email and website, they are recognized as link even though they are not constructed with HREF tagging.

Is there a way to remove the link on them?

Looking forward to your answers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the app you're opening the PDF with that recognizes the email or URL and displays it as a link despite not being explicitly set as such.  There may be a setting in the app to turn this feature off, but it's not going to be in your control if you're generating the PDF to send to others.

If that's your use case and you *really* want to prevent them being links for some reason, you might be able to break the link recognition by embedding a space with tiny font somewhere in the URL/email.

Or close and reopen the span tags in the middle. (`<span>email@</span><span>example.com</span>`).  These are two horrible hacks and I refuse to be quoted on them!

Comment: This is actually a good idea, but separating the link by '<span>' still doesn't work.